# Numpy matrix of strings converted to shared array of strings creates type mismatch

Tags: python, numpy, multiprocessing, ctypes, shared-memory

I am experimenting with [multiprocessing in Python](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process), however, I am having trouble with creating some [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Take the following example that illustrates my problem:

In reference to [the following](https://research.wmz.ninja/articles/2018/03/on-sharing-large-arrays-when-using-pythons-multiprocessing.html) (slightly different as he uses a matrix full of floats, but same principle), I want to convert a numpy matrix of strings into a [shared memory](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes) space for processes to use. I have the following:

```
from ctypes import c_wchar_p
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Array

input_array = np.array([['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
                        ['Purple', 'Orange', 'Cyan', 'Pink']]).T

shared_memory = Array(c_wchar_p, input_array.size, lock=False) # Equivalent to just using a RawArray
np_wrapper = np.frombuffer(shared_memory, dtype='<U1').reshape(input_array.shape)
np.copyto(np_wrapper, input_array)
print(np_wrapper)
```

However, the `np_wrapper` only has the first character of each string:

```
[['R' 'P']
 ['G' 'O']
 ['B' 'C']
 ['Y' 'P']]
```

Things I have tried to rectify the problem:

1. I tried changing the `dtype` of the [`frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) function from `<U1` to `<U6`, which is the `dtype` of the `input_array`. However, it throws the following exception:

> ValueError: buffer size must be a multiple of element size

2. I tried using a `dtype` of [`int64`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.types.html) with the [`frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) function because my `shared_memory` array is of type [`c_wchar_p`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) (i.e. string pointers) and I am on a 64-bit Windows 10 system. However, it throws the following exception:

> ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 4 into shape (4,2)

I am extremely confused why my typing is wrong here. **Does anyone have any insight on how to fix this problem?**

Comment: In `input_array`, the strings are represented as `U6` (24 bytes) items, all packed in the array's `data_buffer`.  They don't reference strings elsewhere in memory, as they would in a list (or object dtype array).  Check the `input_array.itemsize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Preface

**Before I detail my solution**, I want to preface my answer with some helpful information. The function `memoryview()` in python proved to be extremely useful in getting the full picture. For example, run the following after specify the dtype of `input_array` as `dtype='S6'` (b/c less bytes to examine):

```
print(bytes(memoryview(input_array)))
```

Then following results are yielded:

```
b'Red\x00\x00\x00PurpleGreen\x00OrangeBlue\x00\x00Cyan\x00\x00YellowPink\x00\x00'
```

We can see by the following output that each entry in the `input_array` has a length of 6 bytes and is laid out in a contiguous block of memory. This tells us that our Numpy array is not just 8 pointers to strings out in memory.

Turning back to when the `dtype` was **not** specified, @hpaulj additionally provided even more helpful insight. With having read the [dtype documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.dtypes.html), our array has type `<U6`, which translates to as follows:

```
<  -- Little-Endian (b/c I am on an Intel-based system)
U  -- Unicode String (Remember with 4 bytes per Unicode String)
6  -- 24 bytes per entry in the array.
```

---

## Solution

#### TLDR; Here is the solution:

```
from ctypes import c_char
import numpy as np
from multiprocessing.sharedctypes import Array

input_array = np.array([['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
                        ['Purple', 'Orange', 'Cyan', 'Pink']]).T

shared_memory = Array(c_char, input_array.size * input_array.itemsize, lock=False)
np_wrapper = np.frombuffer(shared_memory, dtype=input_array.dtype).reshape(input_array.shape)
np.copyto(np_wrapper, input_array)

print(shared_memory[:])
print(np_wrapper)
```

#### Solution Explanation:

The first incorrect aspect of the initial code was the typing information for the initial `shared_memory` array. Our Numpy array is not an array of pointers, but rather 8 strings compacted contiguously next to each other (with some padding dictated by the longest element). Therefore, using the type `c_wchar_p` (i.e. a string pointer) was **not** correct. I chose `c_char` over `c_wchar` because `c_char` is guaranteed to be one byte, where as `c_wchar` is not ([see documentation for further details](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types)).

Next, one needs to specify the entire size of the shared memory. Because I chose `c_char` as my type, I will be specifying the number of bytes. The length is given by the following:

> There are 8 elements (`input_array.size`) with each element contain 24 bytes (`input_array.itemsize`). Therefore, there are 8 * 24 = 192 bytes total in our shared memory.

Finally, when using the [`frombuffer`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.frombuffer.html) function in Numpy, be sure to specify the **correct** `dtype` because this is how Numpy will be dividing up and interpreting the arbitrary bytes coming in. Just simply use the same `dtype` of the `input_array` to complete the translation.

And finally, once the `copyto` has commenced, the `shared_memory` will have been successfully configured!

Answer (score 1):

It may help to understand what this array of strings contains:

```
In [643]: input_array = np.array([['Red', 'Green', 'Blue', 'Yellow'],
     ...:                         ['Purple', 'Orange', 'Cyan', 'Pink']]).T
     ...: 
     ...:                         
In [644]: input_array.size
Out[644]: 8
In [645]: input_array.itemsize
Out[645]: 24
In [646]: input_array.nbytes
Out[646]: 192
```

Because it is a transpose, the shape and strides differ from the input array, but the strings are in the original order.

```
In [647]: input_array.__array_interface__
Out[647]: 
{'data': (139792902236880, False),
 'strides': (24, 96),
 'descr': [('', '<U6')],
 'typestr': '<U6',
 'shape': (4, 2),
 'version': 3}
```

My guess is that `Array` should be defined with `nbytes` rather than `size`.

Comment: Yeah, I already figured out the solution, give me a second to post my solution (literally typing it as we speak)